# The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE error when executing stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm getting the following error message when attempting to use `MERGE`:

> MMC.SOT_Load package failed to execute, stopped at Step 3 – stepname “SOT”
>   Code: 0xC002F210     Source: Yellow_Fields Execute SQL Task     Description: Executing the query "  DECLARE @RC int    -- TODO: Set parameter values he..." failed with the following error: "The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

This is the SQL I'm using:

```
MERGE   MasterTable     As Target
USING   AcademicAffairs As Source
ON      (Target.Life_Hosp = Source.Life_Hosp) 
AND     (Source.IsValid = 1) 
AND     (Target.IsValid = 1) 
AND     (Target.Life_Hosp is not Null And LEN(Target.Life_Hosp) > 0)
WHEN Matched Then Update 
    Set Target.DEA = COALESCE(NullIf(LTrim(RTrim(Source.DEA)),''), Target.DEA),
    --Target.DPF = COALESCE(NullIf(LTrim(RTrim(Source.DPF)),''),Target.DPF),
    Target.LastName = COALESCE(NullIf(LTrim(RTrim(Source.LastName)),''),Target.LastName),
    Target.FirstName = COALESCE(NullIf(LTrim(RTrim(Source.FirstName)),''),Target.FirstName),
    Target.License_Type = COALESCE(NullIf(LTrim(RTrim(Source.License_Type)),''),Target.License_Type)
;
```

Comment: you know what would help?, if you post the error message

Comment: apologies error message added

Comment: Seems you're not using unique criteria in your join condition.  Compare your results set to see where the duplicates lie and correct the join condition to produce unique rows.

Comment: I can compare by id and yes there are duplicates rows in tables(has been confirmed) but any idea what clause that is?

Comment: Are you using MERGE and only doing something when there is a match? Why not just do a standard update instead?

Comment: The error message is very clear. You have multiple records in your source table that match the same record in your destination table.  What do you mean by what "clause" ? There is only one that is in charge of the matching.